# How to use git master of gst-omx (gstreamer1) for the buildroot package?

Tags: buildroot

I'm testing the current buildroot 2016.02-rc2 release. It contains gstreamer1 packages for version 1.6.3, but I would like to build 1.7.2 instead. I successfully updated package definitions for gstreamer1 and the most important plugins to use 1.7.2. However gst-omx has only a 19 months old release archive for the version 1.2.0 for the direct download (https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/src/gst-omx/) and it fails to compile. So I would like to use the latest version from git repo.

How can I do it? git repository contains a "common" submodule which buildroot's build system cannot handle as it seems. I thought about creating a new release tar.xz package, that would contain everything for building it like all other gstreamer packages, but couldn't find out how those tar.xz packages on the server are generated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is indeed no support for submodule in Buildroot, since most of the time, submodules should be packaged as separate packages.

So, for your own testing, you have two options:

1/ You can do a quick test by creating yourself a tarball that contains all the gst-omx source code (including the contents of the common/) subdirectory.

2/ You can package the gstreamer common stuff as a separate package, make your gst-omx package depend on it, and in a pre-configure hook, create a symlink $(@D)/common -> $(GSTREAMER_COMMON_DIR)